# TinyMCE 4 - getContent() not receiving value from dialog input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, tinymce

For the software I am currently working on I am doing a small little CMS for our internal help documents, but I have been trying to use TinyMCE so that they can easily apply styles that fit our look and feel without needing to understand HTML. I have all of the custom buttons I need working, however I am having trouble with the final custom button.

What we need is a button that will automatically take a word they type as a query string parameter (FindWord?Word=[the input field]) which when clicked on the page later, would pop out a hidden div and anchor to the glossary word. However the getContent() function does not seem to be working for me, and after over 12+ hours of searching, and trying numerous examples, I can't seem to get it to work.

**Other details i am not sure are important:**
-Using MVC 4 with Razor views, TinyMCE 4 with the TinyMCE.Jquery package.
-This is the input field in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGhn5.png

Any help would be great! Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "mceEditor",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: "pagebreak,textcolor,layer,table,save,hr,image,link,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,fullscreen,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,wordcount,code,customcss_1,customcss_2",
    menubar: "edit format view table tools",
    toolbar: "undo redo print glossaryword | fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | bold italic underline strikethrough | outdent alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify indent | bullist numlist hr |",
    contextmenu: "undo redo | cut copy paste | link | customcss_1 customcss_2 glossaryword |",
    height: 500,
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.addButton('glossaryword', {
            title: 'Query String Parameter',
            onclick: function () {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Query String Parameter',
                    body: [
                    { type: 'textbox', name: 'source', label: 'Source' }
                ],
                    onsubmit: function (e) {
                        ed.focus();
                        ed.selection.setContent('<a href="FindWord?Word=' + ed.selection.getContent() + '">' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</a>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Try this in your `onsubmit` after `ed.focus();` -> `ed.triggerSave()` or `tinyMCE.triggerSave()`. OR, you could try this `tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent()`

Comment: @MightyLampshade 

tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent(); does not work.
   
tinyMCE.triggerSave(); does nothing.
      
ed.triggerSave(); is not a function.

Comment: please create a fiddle of your code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around awhile longer I realized I was being silly.

```
setup: function (ed) {
        ed.addButton('glossaryword', {
            title: 'Query String Parameter',
            onclick: function () {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Query String Parameter',
                    body: [
                    { type: 'textbox', name: 'word', label: 'Glossary Word', id: 'popupword' }
                ],
                    onsubmit: function (e) {
                        ed.focus();
                        ed.selection.setContent('<a href="FindWord?Word=' + e.data.word + '">' + e.data.word + '</a>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```